# How would you estimate the algorithmic complexity of this recursive algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I'm just learning the basics of data structures and algorithmic complexity, but I'm confused as to how to analyze recursive algorithms.  Take this for example:

```
def expo_recurs(base, exponent):
    if exponent == 0:
        return 1
    elif exponent % 2 != 0:
        return base * expo_recurs(base, exponent - 1)
    else:
        return (expo_recurs(base, exponent / 2))**2
```

So at most you are calling the recursive function once per level, which eliminates exponential growth.  Each time through you are either taking the odd case or the even case which is performing a either a single multiplication step or a division step and then raising it to the second power.

Would someone mind walking me through how to analyze this, and recursive algorithms in general?

Comment: I think its O(N) where N is the exponent...realy it is O(C*N) where C is a constant ... when C is constant you can just get rid of it .. (in this case C is something like 2/3 ... or something)

Comment: @JoranBeasley It's O(lg n); subtracting one from the exponent makes it even, which means the next call will halve it. The best case (exponent is a power of two) takes O(lg n) time, and the worst case (where exponent/2 is always odd) only takes twice as many calls.

Comment: Notice that O(C*N) is equal to O(N) for any constant C.  Constants are pretty meaningless in big-oh notation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

worst case : For n is odd
f(n)=k+f(n-1);
 
But the next time it will go to else branch because if n is odd , n-1 is even
then the problem will break like this
f(n-1)=k+f(n-1/2);

by mathematical induction
f(n)=k*log(n) or complexity wise O(log(n))

Best case : n is even
Problem breaks into subproblem of half
f(n)=k+f(n/2);

by mathematical induction 
f(n)=k*log(n) complexity wise O(log(n))

So the complexity is O(log(n)) in best and worst case